# pointer is NULL after setting two struct equal each other

Tags: c++, struct

I have two struct describe below. After setting `huffmanTree = tempNode`, the internal pointer right and left of `huffmanTree` are NULL. However, before that the value was still valid but after setting two struct equal each other the value disappeared. What am I doing wrong?

I just want to create a `huffmanTree struct` and initialize it with some data. Then create a `tempNode` having `HuffmanTree *left` point to `huffmanTree` and `HuffmanTree *right` point to new data. When I print out the data from `huffmanTree`, it was NULL

```
// Leaf node
typedef struct HuffmanLeaf {
private:
    char data;
    int count;
public:
    HuffmanLeaf() {

    }

    void setData(char data) {
        this->data = data;
    }

    void setCount(int count) {
        this->count = count;
    }

    char getData() {
        return this->data;
    }

    int getCount() {
        return this->count;
    }
}HuffmanLeaf;


// Huffman tree
typedef struct HuffmanTree {
    HuffmanTree *right;
    HuffmanTree *left;
    HuffmanLeaf huffmanLeaf;
} HuffmanTree;

int main() {
     /* huffmanLeaf[] was defined and initialized 
     .
     .
     .
     . 
     */

    // Take the first two smallest and so on
    HuffmanTree huffmanTree;
    HuffmanTree tempNode;

    // Allocate memory for internal struct
    huffmanTree.left = new (HuffmanTree);
    huffmanTree.right = new (HuffmanTree);
    tempNode.left = new (HuffmanTree);
    tempNode.right = new (HuffmanTree);

    // Two character with least frequency. Create a new Tree
    huffmanTree.right->huffmanLeaf = huffmanLeaf[0];
    huffmanTree.left->huffmanLeaf = huffmanLeaf[1];


    // Next character
    tempNode.left = &huffmanTree;   // have node left point to huffmanTree
    tempNode.right->huffmanLeaf = huffmanLeaf[2]; // new data on node right

    /* Data is still here for tempNode */
    cout << tempNode.left->left->huffmanLeaf.getData() << endl;

    /* Error occured after this */
    huffmanTree = tempNode;

    // Value is NULL
    cout << huffmanTree.left->left->huffmanLeaf.getData() << endl; // Value is NULL
}
```

Comment: Can you show the type of HummanTree::left, the contents of HuffmanTree's destructor and any copy constructors / assignment operators? A quick fix will be to make huffmanTree and tempNode pointers, by the way.

Comment: It worked. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do `tempNode.left = &huffmanTree;`, and after that `huffmanTree = tempNode;`. It would be a miracle if something **didn't** go wrong...

Seriously though, before assignment:

```
huffmanTree is { new, new }
tempNode is { &huffmanTree, new }
```

After the assignment, `huffmanTree is { &huffmanTree, new }`

So your pointer jumping is essentially:

```
huffmanTree->huffmanTree->huffmanTree->huffmanLeaf.GetData();
```

and since you hadn't defined any huffmanLeaf for "huffmanTree", it returns any value it had by default( undefined behavior, since you don't initialize `data` in the constructor as you should )